# Give me some tips for testing Email client mobile application

Tags: manual-testing, mobile, email

I am not familiar with e-mail but I need to test Email client for mobile platform. I suppose that there are some test engineers which can help me to define tricky use cases and well-known problems which could occur. And which articles and standards do I need to learn for better understanding?

Comment: You aren't familiar with email?

Comment: Yes, I am not an expert. I need to test email app for mobile platform and I can do it basically like a common user but how can I guarantee quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather vague. There are different types of email protocols, and your overall test strategy depends on which protocol(s) your client supports.

But, some basic areas for testing email clients on a mobile device include

- Setting up client on device
- Compose card
- Read card
- List view
- Send/receive Attachments,
- Message encodings (Unicode support),
- Performance,
- Rendering text / attachments
- how much of the msg is downloaded,
- first sync
- other mail sync'ing options,
- search on device,
- search on server,
- SSL (incoming/outgoing)
- conversation view
- copy/paste
- folders
- tagging emails
- linked inbox
- sharing
- etc.

Of course this list assumes that you are very familiar with email functionality, and email protocols.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer: email rendering is very important.  Many emails, like newsletters, marketing materials, etc put a lot of effort to make their emails beautiful.  Having the HTML render properly on a mobile client takes effort.

One type of test is the acid test: http://www.email-standards.org/acid-test/
You could also do side-by-side comparisons for many marketing emails, from well known email providers like mailchimp, etc...

Good luck.